# How do I correctly encrypt a string using aes-256-ecb in NodeJS and decrypt with OpenSSL's command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a long UTF-8 encoded string using the `aes-256-ecb` cipher via node.js's built in crypto library. Bellow are my encryption code written tested in node.js (v0.10.24) and corresponding output and decryption command for OpenSSL (OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012) command line.

### Encryption using node.js

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ecb','password');
var plaintext = [ 
  'this is a very long long long long long long',
  'long long long long long long long long long',
  'long long long long long long string!!!!!!!!'
].join('')
console.log(cipher.update(plaintext,'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64'))
```

#### Output

```
XBnU6WZ9wr2GdA1YWZVhsG+mHQ0xlXXc8rAFEud6I/PqfFZL6Pdit7Sm8v+ViKNZmhgTzi7zfg8GHKFntkCDuj6F54TDaWKAdJRftLP9I+22jiKRvYtpD4SDV2oIy93MM5IMbSoBRvXayNF8H9FQnhACM5MHhHX1pLiR4yCg/l6iHH2BDLrwCSifGcGCaQYx
```

### Decrypting using OpenSSL

```sh
echo -n 'XBnU6WZ9wr2GdA1YWZVhsG+mHQ0xlXXc8rAFEud6I/PqfFZL6Pdit7Sm8v+ViKNZmhgTzi7zfg8GHKFntkCDuj6F54TDaWKAdJRftLP9I+22jiKRvYtpD4SDV2oIy93MM5IMbSoBRvXayNF8H9FQnhACM5MHhHX1pLiR4yCg/l6iHH2BDLrwCSifGcGCaQYx' | openssl enc -d -aes-256-ecb -nosalt -a -pass pass:password
```

#### Output

```
bad decrypt
3074361544:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:532:
```

Which one is wrong; my encryption or decryption? And how can I make them compatible with one another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the openssl command you should use -A option to base64 process the data on one line.

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-ecb -nosalt -a -A -pass pass:password
```